# Cannot decrypt session key while regenerating master key with FORCE option

Tags: c#, sql-server, service-broker

When I want to decrypt the `message_body` of Service Broker Queue i got the message

> Cannot decrypt session key while regenerating master key with FORCE
>   option

I alredy tried

```
SELECT TOP(10) cast(Message_Body as XML)
FROM dbo.MyQueue
```

and also using store procedure reference by [the link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166041(v=sql.105).aspx)

Can any one help me why I got this message

Is it any permission issue or any other issue?

Comment: From http://rusanu.com/2007/12/03/resending-messages/ - "This system error is sent to a conversation when the database master key was regenerated with FORCE and the conversation sessions keys (encrypted with the database master key) are lost"

Comment: i am not using any master key for decrypt.
any session key is generated at the time when the row is inserted into Queue?